# How to avoid ValueError: could not convert string to float: '?'

Tags: python

This is ML code and I am beginner.
X and y are  class and feature matrix

```
print(X.shape)
X.dtypes
```

output:

```
Age                  int64
Sex                  int64
chest pain type      int64
Trestbps             int64
chol                 int64
fbs                  int64
restecg              int64
thalach              int64
exang                int64
oldpeak            float64
slope                int64
ca                  object
thal                object
dtype: object
```

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_classif

#Using ANOVA to create the new dataset with only best three selected features 
X_new_anova = SelectKBest(f_classif, k=3).fit_transform(X,y)    #<-------- get error
X_new_anova = pd.DataFrame(X_new_anova, columns = ["Age", "Trestbps","chol"])
print("The dataset with best three selected features after using ANOVA:")
print(X_new_anova.head())
kmeans_anova = KMeans(n_clusters = 3).fit(X_new_anova)
labels_anova = kmeans_anova.labels_

#Counting the number of the labels in each cluster and saving the data into clustering_classes
clustering_classes_anova = {
 0: [0,0,0,0,0],
 1: [0,0,0,0,0],
 2: [0,0,0,0,0]
}
for i in range(len(y)):
     clustering_classes_anova[labels_anova[i]][y[i]] += 1
        

###Finding the most appeared label in each cluster and computing the purity score
purity_score_anova = (max(clustering_classes_anova[0])+max(clustering_classes_anova[1])+max(clustering_classes_anova[2]))/len(y)
print(f"Purity score of the new data after using ANOVA {round(purity_score_anova*100, 2)}%")
```

This is the error I got:

```
#Using ANOVA to create the new dataset with only best three selected features
----> 4 X_new_anova = SelectKBest(f_classif, k=3).fit_transform(X,y)
      5 X_new_anova = pd.DataFrame(X_new_anova, columns = ["Age", "Trestbps","chol"])
      6 print("The dataset with best three selected features after using ANOVA:")

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '?'
```

I don't know what is the meaning of "?"
could you please tell me how to avoid this error?

Comment: What are the variables `f_classif`, `X`, and `y`?

Comment: X and y are, class and feature matrix @gmdev

Comment: Are you importing them or declaring them anywhere else in your code? I don't see where `X` and `y` are defined. Have you tried printing them to see the value of them before you call `fit_transform`?

Comment: yes I declare them and printing before call fit_transform @gmdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of the '?' is that there is this string (?) somewhere within your datafile that it cannot convert. I would just check your datafile to make sure that everything checks out. I would guess whoever made it put a ? somewhere that data could not be found.

can Delete a row using

```
DataFrame=Dataframe.drop(labels=3,axis=0)
'''
With 3 being used as a placeholder for whatever
row holds the ? so if row 40 has the empty ?, you would do # 40
'''
```

Comment: have you any idea how to avoid this error?  Thank you @Sierra Walker

Comment: Not sure what the purpose of your work is so it depends. You could just manually go into the dataset and change the ?, either by converting it to a 0 or just voiding the entire row/column. If it is more professional/formal you can drop a column within python/pandas, which i added to my above answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used ```df1.dropna(how="any")```. code work without error @Sierra Walker